# need to reuse the same %random%

Tags: batch-file

I would like some help about the input at:

```bat
echo Downloading (SUPPOSED TO BE THE SAME AS WHAT IS THE LAST %RANDOM% OBJECT)manager.file
```

I would like to make the in `()` text a text that is the same sentence of the last `%random%` object

What i want to do by the way is a batch file with infinite downloading, but it's just echoes and pings. Here is what I have tried:

```bat
@echo off

:loop
echo Downloading %random%.file
PING -n 0.5 127.0.0.1>nul
echo Downloading (SUPPOSED TO BE THE SAME AS WHAT IS THE LAST %RANDOM% OBJECT)manager.file
PING -n 1.5 127.0.0.1>nul
goto loop
```

Comment: Assign it to a variable. `set myvar=%random%`.

Comment: edited your title. The literal answer to the original title `need list of %***% objects in batch` would be: `set`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this:

What you have to do is to assign the text in a variable.

**1st way:** Using only 1 subroutine (`loop`):

```bat
@echo off

:loop
set "rand=%random%"
set "text1=Downloading %rand%.file"
set "text2=Downloading (SUPPOSED TO BE THE SAME AS WHAT IS THE LAST %rand% OBJECT)manager.file"
echo %text1%
ping -n 0.5 127.0.0.1>nul
echo %text2%
ping -n 1.5 127.0.0.1>nul
goto loop
```

**2nd way** Doing it with 2 subroutines (`set_random` and `loop`):

```bat
@echo off

call:set_random

:loop
call:set_random
echo %text1%
ping -n 0.5 127.0.0.1>nul
echo %text2%
ping -n 1.5 127.0.0.1>nul
goto loop

:set_random
set "rand=%random%"
set "text1=Downloading %rand%.file"
set "text2=Downloading (SUPPOSED TO BE THE SAME AS WHAT IS THE LAST %rand% OBJECT)manager.file"
```

Hope this helps!